# Functions and fetch data in ckan

Tags: python, ckan

I am totally new to Ckan however I have used *Django* and *flask*.Till now I have customized templates in ckan like *create/edit/view* datasets forms . But now I wants to create my own functions so that I can fetch data from db, update data according to my requirements . I have read ckan documentation but till now I didn't found something appropriate. So please can anyone tell me the way I can create my custom function , define urls , interact with db then that will be very helpful or if anyone can provide helpful links to some kind of documentation or videos lectures them that will also be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look into the [different extension points of CKAN in the docs](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/writing-extensions.html). There are extension points to add routes and custom controllers. However, I strongly advise not to interact with the database directly as it will decrease your ability to update CKAN. You can use the action API to change datasets, resources, users, organizations and more.

The interfaces are really flexible and you should be able to implement your customizations using the extension interfaces. If you need help with a specific problem, feel free to write a new question or ask on the mailing list. For general introductions, read the documentation and have a look at existing extensions (repos are often named `ckanext-*`).